# ISR INTO_vect setup

Tags: microcontroller, interrupt, interrupt-handling, attiny

I am attempting the simple task of blinking LEDs using an external interrupt. I am using an ATtiny10 so there is only one pin for interrupts (PB2).

[ATtiny10_datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/Atmel-8127-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny4-ATtin-1315452.pdf)

```
//cpu freq set to 1MHz
#undef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
//io is pin/reg macros.. PB0,PORTB,etc..
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>


ISR(INT0_vect) // Interrupt Service Routine for logical change on INT0 (PB2)
{
    PORTB = 0X0E;        //turn PB0 High
    _delay_ms(2000);
}

int main(void)
{
  // initializations 
  //DDRB 1-output,0-input
  DDRB = 0x0B;        // enable PB0,1,3 as outputs..PB2 is INT0 interrupt... 1011 (3,1,0)
  DDRB &= ~0x04;      //1011 & w/ 1011 (~0x04) keeps bits as we set them 
  PORTB = 0x04;       // H or L for any DDRB output pins, set all Low, 0100 pulls up PB2 resistor since it is an input

  EICRA |= 0x01;      //any logical change on INT0 generates interrupt

  sei();              //enable global interrupts

  while(1){
    PORTB = 0X0E;        //turn PB0 on w/ LOW signal
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB = 0x0F;        //turn all off again
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB = 0X0D;        //turn PB1 LOW
    _delay_ms(500);
    PORTB = 0x0F;        //turn all off again
    _delay_ms(500);
  }

}
```

**MAIN QUESTION**: Did I setup my interrupt incorrectly? I pulled up the internal resistor for INT0 pin PB2. I haven't been able to reach the event for interrupt yet. If additional info is needed please let me know. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The only item missing from my setup was setting the EIMSK (External Interrupt Mask) register. When set to '1' then the External Interrupt feature is enabled. Fun challenge figuring that one out! Don't skip through datasheet kids or else you end up causing more issues!!

```
...
EIMSK = 0x01; //enable external interrupts 
EICRA |= 0x01;

sei();
...
```

Comment: Thanks for that hint. It was exactly my problem.